# Highlight Entire Row Based on Two Variables

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I would like the row of Sheet 1 to be highlighted Red if Column K (Sheet 1) matches Column K (Sheet 2) and Column D (Sheet 2) says "Apple". I will have three variables in Column D to trigger three colors. For example, Apple = Red, Banana = Yellow, and Lime = Green.

What would the conditional formatting be if I wanted to highlight the entire row based on two variables?

Answer (score 0):

Please try selecting the columns to be formatted (say A:Z) Sheet 1, Format > Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is:**

```
=and(match($K1,indirect("Sheet 2!$K:$K"),0)>0,indirect("Sheet 2!$D:$D")="Apple")
```

with red formatting of your choice. Range: should show `A:Z` (extend as required).

Then **+ Add another rule** as above for each of "Banana" and "Lime" in place of "Apple" with yellow and green to suit.

Comment: Thanks you! This is definitely in the right direction. The formatting is working for the values on both tabs, but the highlighting is not the correct colors. All ranges are set to A:AM and the colors are set accordingly. My formulas are as follows: =and(match($K1,indirect("Released!$K:$K"),0)>0,indirect("Ready!$D:$D"&ROW())="Banana") =and(match($K1,indirect("Released!$K:$K"),0)>0,indirect("Ready!$D:$D"&ROW())="Apple") =and(match($K1,indirect("Released!$K:$K"),0)>0,indirect("Ready!$D:$D"&ROW())="Lime")